# How do I find the equation of hyperbola passing through a given point and has given two asymptotes

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, curves

If I know that my hyperbola passes through the point $$(1;1)$$ and has the asymptotes $$2x-y+2=0$$ and $$y=0$$ how can I find the equation of the hyperbola?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I tried sketching it and from that I understand that I have to turn it 45 up degrees and squeeze it but I don't know how to do that mathematically, neither do I know how to sketch it with my computer(without knowing the exact equation) and upload it here, if I could I definitely would. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When $x$ and $y$ are large the curve approximates the pair of straight lines as given by the equations of the asymptotes.
Therefore the hyperbola will have an equation of the form given by the product of the two equations equal to a constant.
So the hyperbola is $$y(2x-y+2)=c$$

Since $(1,1)$ lies on the curve, $c = 3$

Comment: I figured it our this way too, since this is also very applicable to our standard hyperbola $xy=C$ passing through $(1,1)$. But what would (from a teacher's standpoint) be the rationale for this approach, i.e why does this work? How would you present this, other than a "trick out of the hat?"

Comment: @imranfat The way to explain it is to say that, given the curve $y(2x-y+2)=c$, to deduce the equations of the asymptotes, when $y$ is large then $2x-y+2$ must be very small since their product is constant (and vice versa). So here I have applied the same reasoning, but in reverse.

Comment: But how do you reason when $2x-y+2$ is very large? How does that impact the $y$ term since $2x-y+2$ contains a $y$ as well. I know what you are saying, but I am not sure if it is convincing if a linear term contains both variables. From a teacher's point of view, I am struggling a bit with that. I can deliver the method to students, but I find it hard to explain the rationale in a compelling manner if the linear terms contains more variables...

Comment: it suffices to say that when $x$ is very large, $y$ must be very small

Comment: Well, I need to let that sink in I guess...

Answer (score 0):

General equation of hyperbola is $$ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$$

Since $ac\ne 0$ we can assume $c=1$. If we express $y$ we get $$y= {-(bx+e)\pm \sqrt{(bx+e)^2-4(ax^2+dx+f)}\over 2}$$

Now, use that:

- $\lim_{x\to \infty} y =0$ and
- $\lim_{x\to \infty} {y\over x} =2 \;\;$(so $a+2b+4=0$) and
- $\lim_{x\to \infty} (y-2x) =2$

And finally, since $(1,1)$ is on it we get $a+b+1+d+e+f=0$.